# MS Access information before a date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to find employees who were hired before 1991. When I run my query i get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" What does that mean?

This is my query:

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, JOB_CODE, EMP_PCT, PROJ_NUM
FROM employee
where emp_hiredate < '01/01/1991';
```

Ive also tried 01-01-1991 and January 1, 1991 and Tuesday, January 1, 1991.

The format of the hire date in the table is Day of Week, Month, Day#, Year, ie) Tuesday, November 8, 1994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[10 tips for working with dates in Microsoft Access](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-working-with-dates-in-microsoft-access/6135056)

> ## 6 The correct character to use when including a literal date value is the pound character (#).

Your query should be

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, JOB_CODE, EMP_PCT, PROJ_NUM
FROM employee
where emp_hiredate < #01/01/1991#
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, yu should wrap the date with `#` not with single quotes.

```
WHERE emp_hiredate < #01/01/1991#
```

- [browse on Criteria for Date/Time fields](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010066611.aspx)